# Dependent dropdown list in a column

Tags: excel, vba, list, dropdown

**What I need**
Two columns, one with a dropdown list in each row where I can select a code, the other with a dropdown list in each row that is going to show a subcode based on that list selection.

**What I have**
Code that fills all column J with a VBA code:

```
Sub main()
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
lCopyLastRow = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Cells(Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count, "AT").End(xlUp).Row

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("J2").Validation
    .Delete
    'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$AT$2:$AT$" & lCopyLastRow
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

When I try to do the same with the dependent dropdown I get an error.

```
Sub main2()
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("K2").Validation
    .Delete
    'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=OFFSET(Data!$E$1,MATCH($J2,Data!$C$2:$C$6253,0),0,COUNTIF(Data!$C$2:$C$6253,$J2))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

I know the problem is the formula.

[image: error excel vba dropdown list]

[image: error 2 excel vba dropdown list]

[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7immc9Jc-qR_-KcJ5M-dj4tDvFTBxq8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually for one row?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? And which line throws it?

Comment: Also, it would have been nice to see the sample of used data, because I can't get sense of this `=OFFSET(Data!$E$1,MATCH($J2,Data!$C$2:$C$6253,0),0,COUNTIF(Data!$C$2:$C$6253,$J2))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad if i do it with one row using the validation button in excel i dont get and error but if a use VBA i get the error.

Comment: @i get this error: https://imgur.com/d9E3mzT   and this is the line with the error:https://imgur.com/WVAHuZp

Comment: Plesae [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59669991/edit) instead of adding information in comments. Also, can you provide the formula that works when you do it manually?

Comment: added and its the same formula `=OFFSET(Data!$E$1,MATCH($J2,Data!$C$2:$C$6253,0),0,COUNTIF(Data!$C$2:$C$6253,$J2))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad i add the file to the question the example is in the source tab

Comment: @xtrios now it's more clear. So the thing you want to do is: 1. Set a data validation with an in-cell drop-down in column J with a data source in column AT. 2. Based on the choice in a cell in column J you want to set certain data validation in same row cell in column K. If I am right - I still can't understand what should be data source for the column K.

Comment: @Vitaliy Prushak yes exactly thats what i want to do.

Comment: @xtrios  I still can't understand what should be data source for the column K. Can you please explain it step by step, e.g.: I take data from your file - If value in J2 = "10191507" then what validation to K2 should be set?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak 1: If value in j2 = 10191507" then K2 will show a dropdown list with the values from the column E (Data sheet)  that had code  "10191507" in column C.  I have no problem when i try to do that in 1 row, the problem is when i try to do it for the whole column using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is pretty easy, when it's explained properly.

Here is the concept:
**J-cell** is a changed cell in column "J", **K-cell** is the cell in column "K" on the same row as J-cell.
1. Set data validation to column "J" when workbook is opened;
2. Catch every change of any of single J-cells;
3. Generate a validation list based on J-cell's value;
4. Check that such list was created and has values;
5. Set data validation to the K-cell.

Solution:
Ensure concept #1 - create a handler for `Workbook_Open` event
[image: #1]

The code for this is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

' Set data validation to column "J" (concept #1)
SetValidationToJ
End Sub
```

Create a handler for `Worksheet_Change` event, be sure to select the proper worksheet and event.
[image: #2]

The code for this event handler (see comments):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Target - is the changed cell or range of cells
Dim dataArray()

With Target.Parent
    ' the check to catch a change of single cell only
    If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        ' check that this cell in column "J" (concept #2)
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns(10)) Is Nothing Then
            ' if cell was just cleared
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                ' then remove validation from appropriate cell in column "K"
                .Cells(Target.Row, 11).Validation.Delete
            Else
                ' otherwise try to generate validation list (concept #3)
                dataArray = GetValuesForKValidation(Target)

                ' if validation list has some values (concept #4)
                If Not Not dataArray Then
                    ' set validation to appropriate cell in column "K" (concept #5)
                    SetValidationToK dataArray, Target.Row
                Else
                    'if no values - remove old validation as inappropriate
                    .Cells(Target.Row, 11).Validation.Delete
                    '[... your handler for other stuff...]
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

And the rest of code (2 subs and 1 function) is to be placed to regular Module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim dataSht As Worksheet

Sub SetValidationToJ()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sourceRngJ As Range

If dataSht Is Nothing Then Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

With dataSht
    Set sourceRngJ = Range(.Cells(2, 46), .Cells(Rows.Count, 46).End(xlUp))
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 46).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(lastRow, 10)).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & sourceRngJ.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ErrorTitle = "Error!"
        .ErrorMessage = "You must select from provided list!"
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With

End Sub

Sub SetValidationToK(Values() As Variant, RowNum As Long)

If dataSht Is Nothing Then Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

With dataSht
    With .Cells(RowNum, 11).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(Values, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ErrorTitle = "Error!"
        .ErrorMessage = "You must select from provided list!"
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With

End Sub

Function GetValuesForKValidation(SrcRange As Range) As Variant
Dim r As Range, searchRange As Range
Dim output() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

If dataSht Is Nothing Then Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

With dataSht
    Set searchRange = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each r In searchRange
    If r.Value = SrcRange.Value Then
        ReDim Preserve output(i)
            output(i) = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
    End If
Next

GetValuesForKValidation = output

End Function
```

Comments are appreciated.

Comment: Hi i made some changes to the code but basically you solve what i need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example with dependent drop-down lists on the userform.I hope it will be useful for you.
The database includes products, product categories, suppliers of products and prices. Even if the data in the table is mixed, we can comfortably examine the products by grouping them by category and suppliers on linked drop-down lists , the data can be entered to other sheets.

I've defined names on the sheet and used the Dictionary object :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim k As Byte, x As Variant
Me.BackColor = 15658720
For k = 1 To 4
Controls("Frame" & k).BackColor = 15658720
Next
 Supplier = Application.Transpose(Range("Supplier"))
 Category = Application.Transpose(Range("Category"))
 Product = Application.Transpose(Range("Product"))
 Price = Application.Transpose(Range("Price"))
 Set ScDctnry = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For Each x In Supplier
      SD(x) = ""
 Next x
  ComboBox1.List = ScDctnry.keys
 End Sub
```

[Source and sample files here](https://eksi30.com/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-lists-on-userform/)

[image]